# Scheduling for upload in IOS apps

Tags: ios, iphone, whatsapp, viber

I want to start scheduling in my iPhone app to backup my app content, based on user selection[like weekly/daily/etc...], Just want to know which framework is better to launch my app during scheduled time, so that my app should do the backup even in background/killed state.

I have seen the same kind of feature is available in Whatsapp and Viber apps, is anyone aware of what framework they are using to handle this.

Looked at setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval, but I read this doesn't work if app required large time to complete the operation and it may not work application is not used for longer duration by the user. Gone through new BackgroundTasks framework, I am looking for the same kind of framework but this is available from ios 13, but my requirement is to support for older ios versions as well

Comment: Regardless of whether you use the old background fetch API or the new background task API you have the same amount of background time available. Neither of these will work when your app is terminated by the user. You are better off performing the back up while your app is in the foreground, persisting the user's content to a server or perhaps just relying on the user's device backup.

Comment: Hi Paulw11, Its not good idea do upload backup during app is in the foreground, as user is active he expects good performance from the phone, if my app avail the complete processing power and network for upload, so phone becomes slow. So i want to perform this task may be during odd hours/mid nights.

Comment: Unless you are sending very large amounts of data I would be very surprised if a utility thread impacted the performance of your app.

Comment: yes, your expectation is right. Ours is a media backup app and expected to have large amount of data to backup.

Comment: Then you probably won't get enough background execution time anyway. You are limited to 3 minutes

Comment: That is fine, my problem is to invoke my app during the schedule time, once app gets the control planing to use nsurlsession to start the upload, as it will take care of upload even upload takes more than 3 minutes.

Comment: Then background fetch or the new background tasks in iOS 13 are all you have.

Comment: yes, but i want to know is there any option for the devices running with IOS 12 or below to invoke my app at scheduled time[though killed/background] to complete the task.

Comment: There is no way to do something in any version of iOS at a scheduled time (unless you send a silent notification, but even that isn't guaranteed).  If the user kills your app then in this scenario it is dead until they relaunch it. Neither a silent push nor background fetch will launch it.

Comment: From IOS 13 it is possible by using BGTaskScheduler, Yes That is the issue with push notification, i want to launch my app even if it is killed.

Comment: No, even with BGTaskScheduler you cannot force iOS to perform a task at a scheduled time.  You can provide hints as to the earliest and latest that you would like the task performed and that it should happen when the device is connected to power, but there is no guarantee when or if your task will actually execute.  If the user killed your app then they don't want it to run (OK, I realise that actually many people kill apps because they are used to Windows or something and think it will make their phone run better, but it is what it is)

Comment: :) yes that is true for most of users. if that is the case you mean there are no  possibility to achieve my requirement in ios.

Comment: No. It’s nice if an app can do things in the background but you should never rely on it